# Google API to get user review

Tags: php, google-api

Is there any API from google which can help to collect user reviews?

Like review for mexican food in Newyork city.

I checked google API list but could not get it.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults).

> reviews[] a JSON array of up to five reviews. If a language parameter
>   was specified in the Place Details request, the Places Service will
>   bias the results to prefer reviews written in that language. Each
>   review consists of several components:

Comment: thanks, but it's place review, what if I want food, skin surgeon, cloth etc related reviews? any idea?

Comment: I don't believe Google has general reviews anywhere in their API.